# How to inject a dependency based on a condition in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have written a controller which is used for different HTML templates in differet sections in my AngularJS app.

For example, a controller is called differently in two different ways:

1. **Way1:** controller is called while opening a modal. Now `$modalInstance`
   is passed as a dependency, which is not `undefined` in this case.
2. **Way2:** controller is called inside a page div. Now `$modalInstance` is
   `undefined`, but still passed as a dependency, owing to which I get this error 
   *`angular.js:11699 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- MyController`*

I am looking for a way to handle this problem by injecting the dependency `$modalInstance` only when it is defined.

**Example code:**

```
<!-- Common Controller -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope',  '$modal', '$modalInstance', '$filter', 'sharedService', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, $filter, sharedService) {
        /*Code required for to popup*/
        $scope.closeModal = function () {
           $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        /* Remaining code for the controller
         * This code is required for both popup, and other non-popup HTML divs
         */
    }]);         
</script>

<!-- modal HTML -->
<div class="modal-container" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
    <div class="common-html">
        <!-- 
            ***************************
            *** remaining HTML code ***
            *************************** 
        -->
    </div>    
</div>  

<!-- non-modal elemenl HTML -->
<div class="modal-container" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="common-html">
        <!-- 
            ***************************
            *** remaining HTML code ***
            *************************** 
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make it work but it's not very good approach. I would say use different controllers.

Comment: But I don't want to write duplicate code by creating two different controllers which actually have the same code. I want to handle dependency injection more efficiently.

Comment: There are plenty of ways not to duplicate code, of course: parent controller, method delegations, subclassing. What you want is not efficient DI, it's confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: Creating multiple controllers can be one way to solve this problem, but I'm thinking there should be some way to inject dependencies dynamically based on certain conditions.

Comment: Check $injector service.